# Python: How can i send premade email message to input email adress with Tkinter + smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, smtp

How can i send premade message ("Hello, Mister Python", for example) to input email adress with tkinter + smtplib?

One button sender app, but with input adress funciton

Comment: `tkinter` is a GUI library. It has no functionality that will help with emails/networking stuff.

Comment: Tkinter is only a gui package

Comment: smtp + tkinter i mean

Comment: @honeyjohnny Have you looked at any `tkinter` tutorials? It looks like your question is a whole project. Or at least it can be split into: the gui part, and the networking part

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Let us see your attempt to the point you stuck with and we will help you out.

Comment: I don't think the smtp library cares where the data comes from. It's not clear what you're asking, since getting data from a tkinter GUI is straightforward, and passing data to the smtp library is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used tkinter but here how I used python to send emails:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

sender = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
reciever = ["SomeoneEmail@gmail.com"]
password = "SEE BELOW"
msg_body = "Add text here"

# action
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['subject'] = "Python Gmail Generator"
msg['from'] = sender
msg['to'] = reciever
msg.set_content(msg_body)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender, password)

    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

To get the password you will want to navigate to your [App Passwords](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/pwd?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fapppasswords%3Frapt%3DAEjHL4PiLeduNwBgtjx3VAp6hDSOVUUWTSvbLFQ-XFPlKGFDgFjud-W2PCqL_589HT0KpVpgeVdb_oPDxNQj7DaLVOaeymI8xQ&service=accountsettings&osid=1&rart=ANgoxcdBbS2rL_9HSuaodG_AKoJqpKevAHibzBcpgPBFz0LiNafEoUMTXp-iZ7lc8VmZXxjENeA7j0yT9MO3hTsJvAEWGmyX4g&TL=AM3QAYYWKfBO-2lK87ik94BmFDLquGThSt59kEwxB0WVOzqucTg77iSLdUj4Dzj4&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&cid=1&flowEntry=ServiceLogin). Login to your account that the emails will be sending from. Select the app and device you are wanting to use. In my case I choose "Mail" and "Windows Computer". Click on the `GENERATE` button and you will receive a password. Copy and paste that into the password variable we have created.

As for connecting this to your app, I apologize, but I am not sure how to do that at this time. I would suggest looking through the object orientated tutorials and maybe look at using `Kivy` instead of `tkinter`.

Best of Luck!

[image]